# How does FOSUserBundle matches the password from database in symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I was reading the FOSUserbundle various files and they use this function in UserManager

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->findUserByUsername($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No user with name "%s" was found.', $username));
        }

        return $user;
    }


public function findUserBy(array $criteria)
    {
        return $this->repository->findOneBy($criteria);
    }
```

Now these two functions are in `UserManager.php` but they only return user based on password or email. I haven't find any piece of code where password matching is done.

Is that done by symfony or FOSUserBundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOSUserBundle is actually a user provider with user management features. Password matching is done inside Symfony's core security component. See [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php#L54).

Answer (score 0):

The password matching is done by FOSUserBundle in Validator/PasswordValidator.php

Comment: that is the defination class but i want to see where it calls that `isValid()` function